# Putting HTML online using Xampp

Tags: html, xampp, serving

I have created a website in HTML. And I use LAN in my hostel. Currently I am using xampp to run the site on localhost.Now I want to put my website online so that other guys using the hostel LAN could access it. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should either find a machine with a static IP address and configure xampp and your firewall to work with the network. You can then share that IP address with your users.

If you need a domain name, you might want to google for some good hosting providers and upload your website there and configure it with your domain name.